# Big requests issue: GET doesnt release/reset TCP connections, loop crashes

Tags: python, tcp, httprequest, urllib2, python-requests

im using python3.3 and the requests module to scrape links from an arbitrary webpage. My program works as follows: I have a list of urls which in the beginning has just the starting url in it.
The program loops over that list and gives the urls to a procedure GetLinks, where im using requests.get and Beautifulsoup to extract all links. Before that procedure appends links to my urllist it gives them to another procedure testLinks to see whether its an internal, external or broken link. In the testLinks im using requests.get too to be able to handle redirects etc.

The program worked really well so far, i tested it with quite some wesites and was able to get all links of pages with like 2000 sites etc. But yesterday i encountered a problem on one page, by looking on the Kaspersky Network Monitor. On this page some TCP connections just dont reset, it seems to me that in that case, the initial request for my first url dont get reset, the connection time is as long as my program runs.

Ok so far. My first try was to use requests.head instead of .get in my testLinks procedure. And then everything works fine! The connections are released as wanted. But the problem is, the information i get from requests.head is not sufficient, im not able to see the redirected url and how many redirects took place.
Then i tried requests.head with

```
allow_redirects=True
```

But unfortunately this is not a real .head request, it is a usual .get request. So i got the same problem. I also tried to use to set the parameter

```
keep_alive=False
```

but it didnt work either. I even tried to use urllib.request(url).geturl() in my testLinks for redirect issues, but here the same problem occurs, the TCP connections dont get reset.
I tried so much to avoid this problem, i used request sessions but it also had the same problem. I also tried a request.post with the header information Connection: close but it didnt worked.

I analyzed some links where i think it gets struck and so far i believe it has something to do with redirects like 301->302. But im really not sure because on all the other websites i tested it there mustve been such a redirect, they are quite common.

I hope someone can help me. For Information im using a VPN connection to be able to see all websites, because the country im in right now blocks some pages, which are interesting for me. But of course i tested it without the VPN and i had the same problem.

Maybe theres a workaround, because request.head in testLinks is sufficient if i just would be able in case of redirects to see the finnish url and maybe the number of redirects.

If the text is not well readable, i will provide a scheme of my code.

Thanks alot!

Comment: Are you exhausting your file descriptors? If not, my first guess would be that Requests' Connection Pooling is keeping them open to avoid having to re-establish them.

Comment: are you using a `requests.Session()`? Try creating a session first and then the `get` method of this session. This should reuse the connections.

Comment: Thank you guys for the answers. Session doesnt work either. Yes requests keep all the connections open to reuse them, but just when u use a get method, with head it closes them. I was able to solve my problem with urllib2 and opening a fileobject and then later closing it...

Comment: Why do you assume the open connections are a problem? And did you study http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#keep-alive and handle your connections properly?

Comment: I tried the different keep-alive settings but it didnt change anything. Of course i read all possible data to see if it has an impact, but none. I want to use my script parallel for example i can scrape 20 websites at a time. Thats why im worrying about the number of tcp connections.