# How to get all redirected urls with urllib2

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib, http-redirect

Im using urllib2 to get the final url of a link whether there is a redirect or not. My simple code looks as follows:

```
fileobj = urllib.request.urlopen(adress, timeout=30)
url = fileobj.geturl()
```

But when there are several redirects i would like to get all urls of the different redirects. How can i achieve that with urllib2, i was reading the doc but wasnt able to find anything useful. Maybe someone can give me a hint and point me in the right direction?

It would be also possible to use another library, but not requests, because im having trouble with their tcp connection pool.

Thx alot!

Comment: What problems are you having with `requests`? That library explicitly includes a full redirect history.

Comment: As said requests.get keeps open the tcp connections for too long and dont give it back to the pool. Right now im just using the head method where i dont have this problem, but also no redirect history and no chance of getting the final url. Thats why im using a combination of requests and urllib2.

Comment: But anyway Martijn im also interested in the requests case maybe for the future projects. I know i can access the r.history and see the different redirects that took place. But how is it possible to get the url for each redirect? I didnt found anythong on the requests basic and advanced guide. Thx alot!

Comment: I suspect you may be misunderstand Keep Alive connections, where a connection is kept open for reuse for following requests to the same server. For the redirect history, look at the `Location` header on the saved responses.

Comment: See http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#keep-alive on how to manage connections.

Comment: Maybe ur right and i have to overthink my program. But how can it be that when using requests some tcp connections last for hours (as long as my program runs) but when using my workaround with urllib2 it immediately gives them back. What im saying with requests i end up having 7-8 TCP connections to the same server when with my workaround i constantly have 2 or 3? But anyway it doesnt matter that much. I asked that question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024285/big-requests-issue-get-doesnt-release-reset-tcp-connections-loop-crashes

Comment: Ah and for the other question, it works like this: r.history[1].url

Comment: Yes, you can indeed rely on the `url` property if the response as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may build your own opener and subclass `urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler`. You may refer Dive Into Python's [Handling Redirects](http://www.diveintopython.net/http_web_services/redirects.html) chapter. It is very helpful.

Comment: Thx i will have a look at this!

Comment: You may also refer the [urllib2 tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html) for a better understanding of urllib2.